# Welcome aboard!

Tags: discussion

I've been waiting for this forum to open for too long! Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome aboard everyone!

Sorantis, please note that StackExchange is more than a forum alone.

If you haven't already, check out [the about page](http://audio.stackexchange.com/about)... :-)

[image]